# Apply CSS transform to container, but not to content

Tags: css

I have a css transform in a css3 animation that caused a div to flip over. The problem is that the content appears flipped too.

I just want the div to be flipped, but the content to remain unflipped.

Here is a JS Fiddle with my animation taking place on page load: http://jsfiddle.net/ukg4P/

See, the div and the content is flipped. How can I just flip / transform the div, but not it's contents?

Here is the animation, with the transform, that I am using:

```
@keyframes flip{
    0%{
        transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform:perspective(400px) rotateY(-180deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to wrap the inner element in a span and apply the opposite transform :

```
<div class="animated flip"><span class="inner">Settings</span></div>

.inner{
    display:block;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(180DEG);
}
```

#### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/ukg4P/4/)

Comment: I was missing the `display:block;`. Thank you!