# How to apply CSS transition to container div but not contents

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a `div` with a border and a link in it. I want the div to rotate on hover but not the link therein. Essentially I want to see the border rotate the way it currently does, but the text to stay static and not move at all.

[Here's a demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-mclean-zn3s3?file=/styles.css)

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757288/apply-css-transform-to-container-but-not-to-content) to a similar question that suggested I rotate the link text in the opposite direction, but that doesn't work as the text still moves. Or, on hover, it rotates the other way, but if you're inside the `div` and not hovering over the text, then the text still faces the wrong way.

Here's my CSS, applied to a simple html set up:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-container {
  display: inline-block;
  border: white 1px solid;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 3s 2s forwards;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

#button-container:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#button-inner {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: transform 1s;
  margin: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#button-inner:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="button-container"><a href="/" id="button-inner">Read More</a></div>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant ("*[mcve]*") code *in* the question itself, don't rely on people following you around the internet in order to help; questions must - as far as possible - be self-contained, and allow us to accurately and easily reproduce your problem.

Comment: Is the rotation you require just to rotate the border or is there more content that you want to rotate?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I think that's a little harsh - I thought it would be cleaner and easier for people to see it in one demo. Plus, I've been penalised in the past for not including a demo. It's hardly 'following me around the internet' when it's one link to a site - a site that we are suggested to use in order to demonstrate our code.

Comment: @AHaworth I guess I really just need the border to rotate, but I assumed I'd have to rotate the whole div for that to work.

Comment: @Crevulus: I didn't intend to offend you, so I offer my apologies for that. However you say "*I've been penalised in the past for not including a demo*", this time you weren't penalised, your question was closed - because it didn't include the relevant code required to reproduce your problem, this isn't a personal attack on you it's merely an action taken to try and maintain the quality of the site (which, I appreciate, is variable). As for your claim that you posted a demo on a site that "*we are suggested to use...*" I don't believe there's any official guidance behind that 'suggestion.'

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica no offence taken - I get that you're jsut trying to maintain standards. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution for your question to use `pseudo-element`. Not needs to add extra `DOM` element and it's better for performance. I noted in the css snippet what was added or changed.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: serif;
}
body {
  background: #333;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px; /* added */
}

.container {
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

#showcase {
  height: max-content; /* changed */
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  position: relative;
  animation: slideDown 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    top: -5rem;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0rem; /* changed */
  }
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  animation: slideRight 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    left: -100vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

#button-container {
  display: inline-block;
  /* border: white 1px solid; */
  margin-top: 1rem;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  /* animation: fadeIn 3s 2s forwards; */
  /* transition: transform 1s; */
  position: relative; /* added */
  perspective: 500px; /* added */
  transform-style: preserve-3d; /* added */
}
/* pseudo-class added */
#button-container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: white 2px solid;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
/* hover changed */
#button-container:hover::before {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#button-inner {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* transition: transform 1s; */
  margin: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* #button-inner:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
} */

/* @keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
} */
```

```html
<header id="showcase">
  <h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
</header>
<div id="content" class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde accusamus at architecto dolorem! Numquam fuga deserunt nostrum tempora nobis magni sunt voluptatum minus, neque suscipit? Corporis quos sit quo autem magnam inventore consequatur tempora ducimus
  doloribus repellat quisquam labore aliquam, libero ut iusto! Placeat, porro accusantium nam tempore aperiam minus.
</div>
<div id="button-container"><a href="/" id="button-inner">Read More</a></div>
```

Comment: Yep, this is it. Thanks. Are you sure `preserve-3d` is needed? Doesn't seem to have any impact on the animation.

Comment: Yep, maybe you right, because border is a `pseudo-element` and it's inside the `button-container`. Otherwise better to use it. [transform-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style)

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty hack, but will work if you don't want to rotate the text on the opposite side:

```css
.link-background {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.link-background:hover {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
}

.link-container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 70px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="link-container">
  <div class="link-background"></div>
  <a class="the-link" href="#">Link to #</a>
</div>
```

*Although this solution isn't the exact thing you are searching for, I hope you get the point of using `position` and `z-index`*

Answer (score 1):

If you want justthe border to rotate then put it on a before pseudo element and rotate that on the hover. This will keep the content of the actual element unrotated.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 2rem;
}

#showcase {
  height: 20rem;
}

#showcase h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  position: relative;
  animation: slideDown 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    top: -5rem;
  }
  100% {
    top: 5rem;
  }
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  animation: slideRight 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes slideRight {
  0% {
    left: -100vw;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

#button-container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 3s 2s forwards;
  display: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#button-container::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: white 1px solid;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: rotateY(0);
  rz-index: 1;
}

#button-container:hover::before {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

#button-inner {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: transform 1s;
  margin: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#button-inner:hover {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="showcase">
    <h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="content" class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde accusamus at architecto dolorem! Numquam fuga deserunt nostrum tempora nobis magni sunt voluptatum minus, neque suscipit? Corporis quos sit quo autem magnam inventore consequatur tempora ducimus
    doloribus repellat quisquam labore aliquam, libero ut iusto! Placeat, porro accusantium nam tempore aperiam minus.
  </div>
  <div id="button-container"><a href="/" id="button-inner">Read More</a></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The `div` and link should be siblings. and `div` should be positioned `absolute` and fill the parent container. Then rotating `div` won't affect link. I have forked and edited your codesandbox. check it out: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-galois-ig3c1?file=/styles.css)

Comment: Please add your code to the answer, so that others might more easily learn from you, without having to follow potentially dead links around the internet.